# Is there any chance for BJT VBE to be leaked?

Tags: bjt

I tried to design the CE Amp. Everything was fine, but when I tried it on PSPICE, the I_c value differs from the I_c value calculated by I_s and V_BE. 
 In my case, I_s=1e-17 A and V_BE=0.872 V, so I_c value should be around 14 A. However, in the simulation, I_c is measured by around 4 A. 
 Is there any reason for this? Thanks.

Comment: Did your model include bulk resistance? That’s why

Comment: "I_c value calculated by I_s and V_BE" - how did you do this calculation?

Comment: Ic=Is*exp(VBE/VT) I used this equation

Comment: that is not the correct large signal model

Comment: Look at Figure 3 and this part is limited to 100mA  https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/ds30041.pdf    This part is rated for 10A yet they do not spec Vbe vs Ic because of variations so hFE is preferred http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/MJD2955-D.PDF

Comment: Because real transistors have resistance in chip junction in series with Vbe

Comment: @REDOC Please give us the diagram (use the schematic editor.) I want the values of every single part you used. Also, please exhibit your calculations and reasoning for each. I think we can then quickly identify the problem. It might be the Ohmic resistances. But it might be something else. We need to see the circuit and the values of the parts and your calculations.

Comment: @REDOC Are you planning to add a schematic?